# Can Delphi 2007 IDE use Delphi 2010's cgrc.exe while compile RC files?

Tags: delphi, rc

The CGRC.exe in Delphi 2010 support using dot as resource name.  I wish to use it in Delphi 2007 IDE as well.  Is that possible to do so?

In Delphi 2007 IDE, when we compile a project that has .RC file, the build message will show something like:

```
BRCC Command Line
   -w32 -foC:\Users\coder\Project\account.core.res -iC:\Users\coder\Project\developer -dDEBUG C:\Users\coder\Project\account.core.rc
```

However, it doesn't really use BRCC32.EXE to compile the RC files as I rename the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin\brcc32.exe
```

to something else.

Comment: @Chau what do you mean by "support using dot as a resource name"? I can't help feeling that if you explained your problem better rather than moving straight to your solution, you might get better help.

Comment: @Chau also, CGRC is, I believe, just a boot-strapper that spawns RC or BRCC depending on user preference. This is clearly related to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538131/include-file-behave-differently-using-rc-exe-or-brcc32-exe-to-build-rc-files) and it would make a lot more sense if you just edited that question and explained why the answers to it were deficient.

Comment: The dot I meant is having resource entry in rc file like "file.data rcdata file.xml".  I can't use "file.data" as resource entry name in Delphi 2007 or brcc32.exe.  In Delphi 2010/XE, I may use cgrc.exe or "Windows SDK resource compiler" that allow dot in resource entry name.  What I need is a solution that allow me to compile my Delphi project consist of .rc file that has dot in resource name.  Either replace brcc32.exe (that doesn't work) or writing a plug in for Delphi 2007.

Comment: The previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538131/include-file-behave-differently-using-rc-exe-or-brcc32-exe-to-build-rc-files) is meant for Delphi 2010/XE.  But Delphi 2007 doesn't allow us to switch resource compiler.  This question is for Delphi 2007.

Comment: @Chau Chee Yang If you want to use RC, then why don't you just do that. In your build script just call RC rather than BRCC32.

Comment: @Chau Chee Yang The other obvious option is to use a different name for your resource.

Comment: @David: As stated in the subject of this topic.  I wish to do that in Delphi 2007 IDE.  Delphi 2007 IDE use brcc that don't support dot(.) in resource name.

Comment: @Chau let's be clear. You want to build in IDE so no build scripts. That means brcc32. You don't want to change your name to remove the dot. brcc32 doesn't handle the dot. Sounds like you are beaten.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi 2007 evidently doesn't give you an option of what to run. If it already gave you an option to *directly* run RC, then it would provide you no benefit to use CGRC instead. [The documentation tells you](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/CGRC.EXE,_the_Resource_Compiler-Binder) that CGRC does nothing but translate the BRCC command-line syntax into the syntax that Microsoft's RC requires, and then it runs RC.

The utility is probably provided so that the IDE only needs one command-line-generating subroutine instead of two or more. With this utility, the IDE can generate a single set of command-line options, so it only has to vary the EXE file it invokes based on the [project options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Compiler_Options).

It seems that you were hinting at the possibility of *replacing* the `brcc32.exe` file that Delphi 2007 provides with the `cgrc.exe` file Delphi 2010 provides. But Delphi doesn't actually run `brcc32.exe`, apparently. That suggests that the actual resource-compilation ability is in a DLL that's shared by both `brcc32.exe` and the IDE or the code compiler. You don't want to go down the path of replacing DLLs.

So I guess the answer to your question is *no*. You'll have to find some other way of achieving whatever it is you're try to do.

Comment: Yes. I agree with what you suggest.  I compile my project in Delphi 2007 IDE (not command line).  I don't have control over which resource compiler to use in Delphi 2007.  What I need is if there are any ways to use CGRC.exe or RC.exe in Delphi 2007 IDE to compile my custom .rc file that contact dot (.) in resource name.

Comment: It strikes me that the question you should *really* ask is this: "How can I include a dot in a Delphi resource name?" Show your resource-script file, and show the error message you get when you attempt to compile it. (But also be prepared to defend your reason for needing that character in the name at all; you're using named constants in the resource script and in your code, so the exact names shouldn't matter at all.)

Comment: See QC #85202. If you try to get the resource contents from a file (which usually has a dot in its name...) BRCC32 will complain.

Comment: @Ldsandon, getting the resource *contents* from a file is not a problem. The problem is when you want the *name* of the resource to include a dot. That's even what [the QC report you refer to](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=85202) is about, but for a better example, see [QC 544](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=544).

Comment: None of this merits a question here, just change the name of the file and get on with some real work!! Sheesh!

Comment: @Kennedy: I know what the QC is about, because I filed it. I meant you can't store a file in the resource with its name. I said it poorly in English, true.
@Heffernan: that's a real limit of BRCC32, and it's an open bug in QC. You may not be able to change the file name. The only solution is to use RC.EXE and write .rc files accordingly.

Comment: @Kennedy: Is there a way to use IDE's tools api to intercept the event of compiling .rc file?  If this can achieve, I can use cgrc.exe/rc.exe to compile .rc file.

Comment: @Ldsandon, please remember that when you address people with the "@" sign, Stack Overflow uses the *start* of the user name to find a match in order to notify them, and then only the *first* name in the comment. David had to manually check back here to see your response. (I was notified only because it's my answer.) [Details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @Kennedy: My problem may solve if there are ways to prevent the compilation of .rc files using ToolsApi.pas.  Unfortunately, I can't find any solution to prevent compilation of .rc files in Delphi 2007 IDE.

Comment: @Chau, doesn't the invalid syntax prevent compilation?

Comment: @Kennedy: Here is what I try to do.  I use ToolsApi to register an IOTAIDENotifier handler.  In BeforeCompile event, I attempt to use use cgrc.exe to compile the .rc file.  This works!!  However, once BeforeCompile is done, Delphi will compile the .rc file again using brcc32 and it will override the .res file I compile using cgrc.exe.  If I can find a way to prevent Delphi compile .rc file using brcc, my problem will solve.

Comment: @Chau Chee Yang: you have to remove the .rc file from the project, just link the .res file. As long as the IDE finds a .rc file in the project it will compile it.

Comment: @ldsandon: Thank. I think this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 2007 the only way I found is to run RC.EXE or in a pre-build script or in a build tool script (I use CCNet).